# Scrolling UIScrollView after nested UITableView scroll end

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, scroll

I have scrollable UITableView inside of UIScrollView. TableView is scrolled separately. I want to make UIScrollView scroll down, when a user scrolls to the end of UITableView and continues scrolling.

Answer (score -1):

set scrollview content size . scrollview..contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,800);

Comment: I don't think you understood the question:
There is a long full-screen-width scrollview, which works ok. There is a tableview in it 200x150. It also works ok. When you scroll the list in tableview at some point the list comes to an end. I want the scrollview to start scrolling, when user continues scrolling after list end.

Comment: @ValentinStoianoff I have got the same issue. Have you found the answer yet? without addind sections to the tableview or a footerview.